# Upload an image to the firebase storage (MERN application) and render success or failed messages in the UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload, firebase-storage

The problem is that when I try to upload an image of size more than 2MB, it should show an error message under the  tag but instead it shows uploading message first, following with "Image uploaded successfully" and at the end error message is displayed i.e., "Error uploading image (file size must be less than 2 MB)".
This functionality works well but only the order of displaying error isn't working as expected when file size is 2MB+.

Tried to fix this for a while but doesn't seem to work anyway. The same code worked well in other project but it is not the same here.

In case error occurs while uploading, imageError state is changed to true which should display only error message in the UI.

---Profile.jsx---

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  getDownloadURL,
  getStorage,
  ref,
  uploadBytesResumable,
} from "firebase/storage";
import { app } from "../firebase";

const Profile = () => {
  const fileRef = useRef(null);
  const [image, setImage] = useState(undefined);
  const [imagePercent, setImagePercent] = useState(0);
  const [imageError, setImageError] = useState(false);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({});

  const { currentUser } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (image) {
      handleFileUpload(image);
    }
  }, [image]);

  **const handleFileUpload = async (image) => {
    const storage = getStorage(app);
    const fileName = new Date().getTime() + image.name;
    const storageRef = ref(storage, fileName);
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, image);
    uploadTask.on(
      "state_changed",
      (snapshot) => {
        const progress =
          (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
        setImagePercent(Math.round(progress));
      },
      (error) => {
        setImageError(true);
      },
      () => {
        getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) =>
          setFormData({ ...formData, profilePicture: downloadURL })
        );
      }
    );
  };**

  return (
    <div className="p-3 max-w-lg mx-auto">
      <h1 className="text-3xl font-semibold text-center my-7">Profile</h1>
      <form className="flex flex-col gap-4">
        <input
          type="file"
          ref={fileRef}
          hidden
          accept="image/*"
          onChange={(ev) => {
            setImage(ev.target.files[0]);
            setImageError(false);
          }}
        />
        <img
          src={currentUser.profilePicture}
          alt="profile image"
          className="h-24 w-24 self-center cursor-pointer rounded-full object-cover mt-2"
          onClick={() => fileRef.current.click()}
        />
        **<p className="text-sm self-center">
          {imageError ? (
            <span className="text-red-700">
              Error uploading image (file size must be less than 2 MB)
            </span>
          ) : imagePercent > 0 && imagePercent < 100 ? (
            <span className="text-slate-700">{`Uploading: ${imagePercent} %`}</span>
          ) : imagePercent === 100 ? (
            <span className="text-green-700">Image uploaded successfully</span>
          ) : (
            ""
          )}
        </p>**
        <input
          defaultValue={currentUser.username}
          type="text"
          id="username"
          placeholder="Username"
          className="bg-slate-100 rounded-lg p-3"
          autoComplete="off"
        />
        <input
          defaultValue={currentUser.email}
          type="email"
          id="email"
          placeholder="Email"
          className="bg-slate-100 rounded-lg p-3"
          autoComplete="off"
        />
        <input
          type="password"
          id="password"
          placeholder="Password"
          className="bg-slate-100 rounded-lg p-3"
          autoComplete="off"
        />
        <button className="bg-slate-700 text-white p-3 rounded-lg uppercase hover:opacity-95 disabled:opacity-80">
          Update
        </button>
      </form>

      <div className="flex justify-between mt-5">
        <span className="text-red-700 cursor-pointer">Delete Account</span>
        <span className="text-red-700 cursor-pointer">Sign Out</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Where does the check for the maximum file size happen?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have specified the max size that a user can upload in the firebase storage rules:
--->
allow read;
allow write: if
request.resource.size < 2 * 1024 * 1024 &&
request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.*')
<--

In case the image size is larger than 2MB, it should throw  an error and setError state to true so that I can display upload failed message in UI when it is true. But first upload success message is displayed (even when it is not saved in the firebase base storage) and then the upload failed message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You (only) enforce the maximum file size in the security rules of Cloud Storage, and those rules are only applied once the upload has completed. To prevent uploading a file that is larger than you want, you should check its size in the client-side code **before starting** the upload, e.g. by checking its [`size` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/size).